# Share raid lockouts between your characters

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I like to collect mounts and I have 6 alts and my main character, I would like to farm mounts in all my characters, like Invencible from 25H Lich King, but if i clear the entire raid with every character, it'll take just too much time, is there a way to share the lockout from my main character to the alts? so when they got into the raid, they can like, go straight to to Lich King? 
All the characters are in the same Realm and Account.

Answer (score 5):

> You need ONE character saved to the instances cleared to the endboss.
>   This can be a low-level alt (70/80) or a level 100, but he WILL NEVER
>   kill the boss. This character will extend all lockouts weekly Like
>   This. to get the save, you can clear the instances on this char or
>   invite it to be inside the instance as you or someone else kill the
>   second to last boss on a different account. clearing the instance can
>   be done on normal 10m. you can also get the save by joining any group
>   finder achieve/transmog group and leaving before the end boss. you can
>   skip optional bosses in ulduar / ICC, in Firelands you need a 4/7 save
>   with alysrazor / majordomo / rag still up. THESE SAVES MUST BE ON
>   NORMAL MODE, NOT HEROIC.
>
> now you can go directly to the mount bosses
>   with all your other alts (preferably geared and level 100), solo,
>   every week. log into your saved alt, get someone to invite you (friend
>   or your own 2nd account). log out and get on a farming alt, same
>   person invites you AND MAKES YOU LEADER. that's it: that other person
>   can now leave the group, they do not have to enter any instance, they
>   get saved to nothing. you are now in group with your own offline alt.
>   Fly to Ulduar, set to 25m before entering. then go to ICC, enter in
>   25man normal, when INSIDE change to heroic. go to Firelands and clear
>   the 3 bosses on 10 or 25 (I do Alysrazor / Rag on 25 but zone out to
>   change to 10 for majordomo since it's a pain on 25), i dont think
>   there is any advantage to using heroic for firelands mounts. same for
>   any other raids. if you have more farming alts, you will need to
>   repeat the above process of invites, or just have that friend invite
>   all your farming alts one by one in the first place. as you finish
>   with one, leave group, log into the next one - it is now the leader.
>   reset all instances and zone in. and so on.
>
> Finally here is something
>   for those without friends and/or with social phobias: you can do all
>   this with a single account. Create a custom LFG tool premade group
>   with farming alt, name it something like "test group dont join". log
>   into the saved alt and apply to this group, log back into farmer and
>   accept application, then back to saved and accept group invite, then
>   back to farmer and leave the LFG tool. now you are group leader with
>   your offline saved alt, ready to farm. repeat with other farming alts.

source: [/r/wow](https://www.reddit.com/r/wow/comments/2usvqn/how_to_farm_old_mounts_quickly/)

Comment: For anyone as confused as I was when reading this: The lockout doesn't get shared to the offline alt. Related line from comment in the linked Reddit thread "Note: Your offline character will not get saved for boss kill while in group."